# how to ignore removing a special character in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I am trying to strip all non numbers and this symbol `*` from a string.

An example would be

```
Input: "gdfgdf234dg54gf*23oP42"
Output: "23454*2342"
```

I have the following which removes everything apart from numbers. The issue is that it also removes the `*`. I am unsure how to ignore one character.

```
string.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

I am sure I will get ridiculed on here saying what else have I tried, but have searched for numerous answers on here.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to extend that character class yourself: `[^\d*]` instead of `\D`.

Comment: @B--rian potentially. It is quite hard to read those answers as there often isn't a good explanation as to what each symbol does. Even the answer below is a bit cryptic without an explanation

Comment: Well, `/[^\d*]//g` is equivalent to `/[^0-9*]//` and means that all characters which are not (that is the `^`) between `0-9` (numeric) or `*` will replaced with empty string `//` aka deleted. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Try `[^\d*]`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I7UtHj/2/)**

```js
console.log("gdfgdf234dg54gf*23oP42".replace(/[^\d*]/g,''))
```